# HTTP ERROR 500 when using model in routes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I got HTTP ERROR 500 after putting using models in the routes file.

Here is the routes file code:

```
use App\User;
use App\Address;


Route::get('/hesham', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/insert', function(){
   $user = User::findOrFail(1); 
   $address = Address::create([
    'name'=>'1234 Housten av New York',
    'user_id' => $user->id
]) 
  $user->address()->save($address);
});
```

Home Route is working fine, but /insert is giving 500 ERROR

Here is the user model

User.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}


public function address(){

    return  $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

Here is the Address model
Address.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    //
}

public function user(){

    return  $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: post your models user and address.

Comment: @btl I edited the post with my models

Comment: @KirkBeard There is no errors in the log

Comment: 500 is internal server error, there will be a log, turn on error_reporting and ini_set('display_errors', true) and all that

Comment: tail -f storage/logs/laravel-2017-06-25.log

Comment: @Dale I did, but there is no error appearing from this action, i think the problem in the code

Comment: Just do everyone a favor and read the manual bro

Comment: @Dale sorry for distracting but can you tell me which manual i need to read ??

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

```
public function address(){

    return  $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

and conversely:

```
public function user(){

    return  $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

To associate an address with a user, do this:

```
Address::create([
    'name'=>'1234 Housten av New York',
    'user_id' => $user->id
])
```

**edit**

try this:

```
$address = new Address();
$address->user_id = $user_id;
$address->name = '1234 Housten av New York'
$address->save();
```

Comment: I did these changes, but still facing the issue. I edited the post with the new code, can you check it ?

Comment: as @Dale stated, 500 is an internal server error, can you pull up your apache/nginx logs?

Comment: Add protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id']; to your Address model.

Comment: still nothing changed

Comment: you mean the Route get insert be like this: $user = User::findOrFail(1); 
 $address = new Address();
$address->user_id = $user_id;
$address->name = '1234 Housten av New York'
$address->save();

Comment: yes I'm just seeing if it's a problem with mass assignment.

Comment: still the same :(